# Output a value for each iteration of a loop

Tags: ruby, fixnum

I want to output a value for each number in an integer. To better explain, I want to do something to the effect of:

```
10.each do
  *
end
```

Which would output:

```
**********
```

I'm pretty sure there's an easy way to do this, but I'm drawing a blank... Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"*" * 10
```

Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Haha, um actually yes. I just couldn't think! Thanks.

Comment: What if I wanted to do the same thing with an image? like `image_tag "/path" * 10`?

Comment: Got it `<%= (image_tag "/image.png") * 10 %>`

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's `String` class has a handy [`*`](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#M001490) method just for this purpose.

```
'*' * 10 # => **********
```